# JavaFX: добавить кнопки и события TaskBar

Tags: java, javafx

Добавляю кнопки:

```
Long ndl = com.sun.glass.ui.Window.getWindows().get(0).getNativeHandle();
ITaskbarList3 list = null;
try {
    list = COMRuntime.newInstance(ITaskbarList3.class);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Pointer<?> hwnd = Pointer.pointerToAddress(ndl);
Pointer<ITaskbarList3.THUMBBUTTON> buttons = Pointer.allocateArray(ITaskbarList3.THUMBBUTTON.class, 1);
ITaskbarList3.THUMBBUTTON btn = buttons.get(0);
list.ThumbBarAddButtons((Pointer<Integer>) hwnd,1,buttons);
```

Появляется пустая кнопка

[image: ITaskbarList3]

Как теперь к ней привязать какое то действие и иконку?